# While using SUM Formal it's getting error (No Value Input)

Tags: google-sheets

ARRAYFORMULA(SORTN(TEXT(
GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOG", "price", DATE(2020,1,1), DATE(2021,2,1), "daily"),
{"yyyy mm", "@"}), 9^9, 2, 1, 0))

I have used above Formula.
Data get from above Formal has no value input

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20rNn.jpg)

While Using Sum formula is Shown Errors (0)

Comment: the numbers are *text*-based/formatted. try: `=index(sum(--D14:D26))`